# PowerShell, Exchange 2010 - comparing variable returns incorrect results

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I'm having a problem comparing a variable.

Can someone please enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong?

"account.name" is the SamAccountName in this example.

> $DN = (Get-Mailbox account.name).DistinguishedName
>
> $DN

Returns: CN=Account.Name,OU=Users,OU=IT,OU=Science Lab,DC=company,DC=com

> $DN.GetType().Name

Returns: String

> Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {Members -eq "$DN"}

Returns: nothing

> Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {Members -eq "CN=Account.Name,OU=Users,OU=IT,OU=Science Lab,DC=company,DC=com"}

Returns: correct results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `-Filter` parameter uses a scriptblock. Try it this way:

```
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("Members -eq ""$DN""")
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter $scriptBlock
```

Comment: Thanks Bill !  That works!  And I just applied it to a similar situation:

This wasn't working:
ForEach ($Mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox"}))
{ Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq "$Mailbox.UserPrincipalName" }

So I used your advice and did it this way:
ForEach ($Mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox"}))
{
   $ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("UserPrincipalName -eq ""$($Mailbox.UserPrincipalName)""")
   Get-ADUser -Filter $ScriptBlock
}

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes.

```
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {Members -eq $DN}
```

Will do it.

The reason it returns nothing is because with the quotes its looking specifically for $DN, rather than the data that variable contains.

Comment: Removing the quotes doesn't work. The variable will actually be evaluated as `$null`. See my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to do this, using "quotes" instead of {scriptblock}:
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter "Members -eq '$DN'"